# Should Parenting.SE opt out of HNQ: Yes or No?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, hot-questions

Referring to [this question](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/should-parenting-opt-out-of-hot-network-questions-trial-run) about opting out of the HNQ (hot network questions) listings, what shall we as Parenting.SE do?

Below this question are two answers:

- [One to opt-out of no longer appearing in the HNQ list when we have a popular question.](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1314/4348)
- [One to continue to be listed on the HNQ when we have a popular question.](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1315/4348)

Pick one and upvote it like you would in a poll. Let's lock this question after 20 days (Jan 10th, 2019). That should be enough time to let everyone come and vote.

Edited to add: **Downvotes will not be counted**. Each person has one vote. Use it to support your choice. (Downvoting unfairly gives you two votes. That's not representative of the community.) Thanks.

Comment: Closed as the poll has completed

Comment: @RoryAlsop I locked the question instead so that the vote totals will not change.

Answer (score 7):

## No

#### Don't opt out!

I don't want Parenting.SE to opt-out of being visible on the HNQ.

This means that popular questions will continue to be visible on the HNQ.

Comment: I can't vote on my own post, so take this as a +1 for this answer.

Comment: I'm in favor of opting out and upvoted that post. I'll upvote this answer for you, @SomeShinyObject, since you can't. Then we can directly compare the score.

Comment: Thanks @AnneDaunted. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

#### Opt out!

I want Parenting.SE to opt-out of being visible on the HNQ.

This means that questions asked on Parenting.SE will no longer be visible on the HNQ.

Comment: SE sites are suppose to be about evidence based answers, yet much of parenting Parenting is about emotional opinion. Contrary to the engineering sites, hot questions in SE Parenting tend to be ones where people have different emotional opinions, rather than different techniques.  Broadcasting those "hot (button) network questions" to other sites is likely to mostly attract more emotionally charged answers, which doesn't help build the site or build the community.