# Parenting will remain on the HNQ

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

@SomeShinyObject [raised our poll](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1313/316) asking the community whether we should opt out of the Hot Network Questions list, as on the one hand they bring new visitors, but on the other, the rapid influx of new people who sometimes don't know the site rules can cause a bit of friction.

We would have loved it if more had voted, but the results are in and the vote is for Parenting.SE to remain part of the HNQ. (8 upvotes to 5 - each option gained 1 downvote)

So what I would ask of the community is to be aware of questions that pop onto the HNQ, as rapid dealing with trouble becomes more important, so flag early, use your up and down votes, and leave comments to help steer new visitors.